Will be counted as Good Karma or Bad Karma?
I am a newbie here and I don't have much knowledge of ancient texts, so if this question is silly or offensive, please let me know, I will delete it.
Now, for my question, here is the senerio:
In a forest, there is a lion who is almost dead. It didn't succeeded in hunting. Now, suppose I am a hunter and I was just roaming about in the forest with a loaded gun. I saw the lion running to hunt a deer. Now, the thing is, if I save the deer from being hunted by lion, will it be counted as my good karma for saving the deer, or it be counted as bad karma for taking the food from lion's mouth. Also, suppose I didn't saved the deer, then will it be counted as bad karma for not saving someone's life, or it be counted as good karma for letting lion grab its food.
Similar case arises when we clean our houses on occassions like Diwali, etc. Mostly, our houses has spider webs developed over time. So, on some special day, everyone cleans their houses and removes those spider webs. So, my question is, will it be counted as good karma for cleaning the house, or it be counted as bad karma for destroying someone's (spider's) house?
This question just randomly came into my mind, so I thought this would be a good place to ask and clear my doubts.

Well in Gita it’s said, even a leaf moves by His will. Seems like our Sanchita and Prarabdha karmas influence our buddhi and buddhi influences our mind to do things. Your critical thinking here shows you have some past karmas on non violence or some karmic dept from the spider u killed or going to. Things things will go crazy. You can read ahogra series(3rd book) better complete 3 books. If you find some insight please share. Everyone is learning.

@SpiritualSeeker Actually, this Diwali, I was cleaning my house and I was removing the spider webs. From here, this thought came into my mind. Then I went on thinking about this and the lion's case came into my mind after few minutes.

@SpiritualSeeker Well in Gita it’s said, even a leaf moves by His will, which means that there is no requirement of karma? So, if god doesn't want me to do anything good, will I be able to do good, or I would act according to god? If I would be acting according to god, then why there is need of karma?

I have very limited knowledge. I hope some advance folks answers your doubts.
